# Disable the "Add New" button in Rad Grid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radgrid

So I have Rad Grid that contains data and I have in above the `Add New Button`. I want when user has permission to add to make it enable if he doses not have then its disable I search for hours for a solution and all I come is this code:

```
Dim cmditem As GridCommandItem = CType(gvDefCountry.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)(0), GridCommandItem)
Dim ctrl As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button = CType(cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
ctrl.Enabled = False
```

But every time I run the code, I'm getting this error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

The view looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
If (TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditableItem) AndAlso (e.Item.IsInEditMode) Then

        For Each cmdItm As GridCommandItem In RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)
            Dim Addbtn As LinkButton = CType(cmdItm.FindControl("InitInsertButton"), LinkButton)
            Addbtn.Enabled = False
            Dim btn As Button = CType(cmdItm.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton"), Button)
            btn.Enabled = False
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: i do not want to hide it i want to just disable it can not click it but its shown

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Where do you put the codes? if you put it in `gvDefCountry_PreRender` event of the grid, it will work just fine.

However, i would recommend you to hide the button altogether instead of disabling it, since there will be no visual difference between enabled and disabled state of the button, depending on the skin you use (In my case - Metro). Otherwise, you also need to change the styles to grey it out and remove the mouse hover effect.